# query that groups by different columns including time difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-concat, gaps-and-islands

I have this simple query that returns a weeks worth of soccer games.

```
select game_group, game_name, game_date, game_StartTime, game_EndTime
from Games
where game_date between '10/1/2018' and '10/7/2018'
```

With results like this:

```
 Junior   | blue_red     | 10/1 | 8:00  | 8:30
 Junior   | blue_red     | 10/1 | 8:30  | 9:00
 Junior   | blue_green   | 10/1 | 9:00  | 10:30
 Freshman | brown_purple | 10/1 | 12:00 | 12:30
 Freshman | black_white  | 10/1 | 12:30 | 1:00
 Freshman | yellow_pink  | 10/3 | 3:45  | 5:00
 Senior   | blue_orange  | 10/4 | 7:00  | 7:30
 Sophmore | pink_red     | 10/4 | 7:30  | 8:30
 Sophmore | green_purple | 10/4 | 8:30  | 9:00
```

Is there a way to manipulate the query, so that it groups the games by date and times?  The logic would be, combine games that are in the same group, on the same date and within 30 minutes or less of each other...so the grouping factors would be game_group, game_date, and the 30 minute difference between game_StartTime and game_EndTime...

like this:

- schedule # 1 is: Junior, blue_red;blue_red;blue_green, 10/1, 8:00 to 
  10:30
- schedule # 2 is: Freshman, brown_purple;black_white; 10/1,    12:00
  to 1:00
- schedule # 3 is: Freshman, yellow_pink, 10/3, 3:45 to    5:00
- schedule # 4 is: Senior, blue_orange, 10/4, 7:00 to 7:30
- schedule # 5 is: Sophmore, pink_red; green_purple, 10/4, 7:30 to 9:00

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This sounds like your typical groups and islands problem. It has been asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: @Brian I tried a bunch of different 'group by' ideas but I couldn't work out combining by the needed times

Comment: @SeanLange groups and islands?  Maybe I searched using the wrong terms, I've never heard of that before.  I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: I meant to say "gaps and islands". :D

Comment: Looks more like a group_concat() variation to me.

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks, I'll see if I can find some info on that function

Comment: @TabAlleman I reviewed group_concat and while it does appear useful, I don't see how it would give me the ability to group by times that are equal or less that 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to do is to use a combination of approaches to common problems.

You first need to use a "Gaps and Islands" approach to get a CTE or derived table that looks like this (using abbreviations and partial sample data to keep it short):

```
Group   Game     Date   Start   End    GroupSequence
Fr      B-P      10/1   12:00   12:30  1
Fr      B-W      10/1   12:30    1:00  1
Fr      Y-P      10/1    3:45    5:00  2
```

`GroupSequence` is an artificial column that you calculate in the CTE using a "Gaps and Islands" solution.   All the games in the same group, on the same day, that are less than 30 minutes from the previous `end` to the subsequent `start` will share the same `GroupSequence`.

Then you select from that CTE, grouping by `Group`, `Date`, and `GroupSequence`,  using the GROUP_CONCAT technique to build the `Games` column, and building your `Time Range` columns with the `MIN(Start)` and the `MAX(End)`.